# Slope-composition chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know that it is formally not a programming question, but I still hope not to be very heavily downvoted for it. I am in fact looking not for the code itself but for the defining the right chart type to implement.

If there are two parties, both participated in elections in 1996, and 2001. And some of the voters stayed with the same party from one elections to another, and some of them switched, is it possible to chart such a slope-composition chart in R, and what is the right way doing it?

Here is a draft of what I have in mind.
[image]

Comment: Please provide the input data in a reproducible form.  See [mcve].

Comment: you might be looking for a Sankey diagram ... there are some R implementations

Comment: @BenBolker: YES! thank you!

Comment: It's also called a parallel sets plot. There's a very nice implementation in the development version of the ggforce package. May require some effort to get  to run, but should produce very nice results. https://twitter.com/thomasp85/status/900430849648275456

Comment: In fact, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47104555/4975218

Comment: @ClausWilke: That is fantastic. Exactly what I was looking for